# How can I get back unused space

Tags: sql-server

How can I get release unused space to the OS ?

[image]

I tried

```
DBCC SHRINKDATABASE(QlikDataWarehouse, truncateonly)
```

But nothing happens , any suggestion ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I shrink my SQL Server Database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/439071/how-do-i-shrink-my-sql-server-database)

Answer (score 0):

Your `truncateonly` parameter [doesn't allow SQL Server to rewrite data to free up space](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190488.aspx). Back up the database (necessary to allow the transaction log to be truncated), then shrink it without the `truncateonly` option.